# create new python file based on template

Tags: python, node.js

I would like to create a new python file based on a template. For example:

**very basic template:**

```py
info = {
  "name": "",
  "last_name": "",
}

print(f'My name is {info["name"]} {info["last_name"]}')
```

This template I would be using in `node.js`, where I would pass the `name` and `last_name` to the python file, and everything would work, like so:

> from `node.js`:

```js
require('child_process').spawn(
  'python',
  [
    'path_to_python_template.py',
    'John',
    'Doe',
  ],
);
```

> to `python`:

```py
import sys

info = {
  "name": sys.argv[1],
  "last_name": sys.argv[2],
}

print(f'My name is {info["name"]} {info["last_name"]}')
```

---

### The issue

My issue is that I would like to save the content of `name` and `last_name` in a new python file, so I could reproduce what was done.

For example:

```py
info = {
  "name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
}

print(f'My name is {info["name"]} {info["last_name"]}')
```

Note that my main goal is to replace in a new file:

`sys.argv[1]` by the actual input: `John`, and

`sys.argv[2]` by the actual input: `Doe`.

Ideas?

Comment: So, you want to create an actual `.py` file? And you have no commas in the arguments, so why did you think splitting would help?

Comment: Overall, if you want to use Node, try using Pug templates or some other actual _template engine_. Why do you need to spawn a python process?

Comment: it is because I am running this file using node.. then my goal is to save what was passed to the file

Comment: Why not just log what is passed to the python file and store your log rather than writing a file/template? Either way this question hasn't shown what you've tried to do and where it's failed.

Comment: I am already saving a log, but I also want to write this new file

Comment: either way you need to show some working... what you've tried and what's failed.

Comment: I haven't found anything online that could at least give me a direction, so I don't know how to start.. that is why I posted the question.. could you help me out?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really for that, you're gonna need to start somewhere before we can help... otherwise you might be best hiring a professional.

Comment: If you want to create a file with textual replacements, then you need to actually **write a file**. Neither your Node or Python code are doing that. Start there. And (like I said), a template library can help with that

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.. thanks for the direction